# Going through array with html_safe or raw returns escaped html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array in my view file. Each value in the array contains html. I want to go through the array and not escape the html. However, whenever I run `html_safe` or `raw`, the array is displayed with non-escaped html. Below are some of the methods I tried that proved a failure.

This returns the array with escaped html...

```
<%= @posts.each { |x| puts raw(x) } %>
```

This returns with each value in the array as nil...

```
<%= @posts.map { |x| puts raw(x) } %>
```

Finally, inspect returns the array with escaped html...

```
<%= @posts.inspect { |x| puts x.html_safe } %>
```

This returns with nil as well...

```
<%= @posts.map { |x| puts x.html_safe } %>
```

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is with the `<%=` at the start of every example - this will output the result of the expression, which is `@posts` itself.

Replace it with `<%` and see how you go.

edit: The first example is the one I would use, with each and raw.

edit again: puts really isn't typical in views - try something like the following:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So I chose my first example and took out `=` but now it returns with nothing. I don't see any of the values or html from my array and nothing in my page source. Whereas if I use `<%= @posts.join() %>` then my values are shown. But for numerous reasons I don't want to use join. Thanks for the shot though.

Comment: You saved my life man, i had been struggling over this for about 3 hours.!!